# How can I deploy the MobileFirst Application Center in Bluemix?

Tags: deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

Is it possible to deploy the MobileFirst 8 Application Center in Bluemix? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Bluemix Containers or one of the servers Bluemix provides.

Take a look at Applications Center's software [requirements](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=366EEBA00BA011E5A377F80D5A43BD22&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CMobile%20OS%7CWindows&duComponentIds=S002&mandatoryCapIds=1%7C13%7C132%7C26&optionalCapIds=30%7C9%7C121%7C26)

As long as the correct hardware is behind Bluemix I'm sure any of the servers Bluemix has to offer will work. I have not heard anyone try it yet though, you can be the first :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for deploying Application Center on Bluemix with Liberty buildpack as the runtime follow this [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/22/running-mobilefirst-foundation-appcenter-on-bluemix/).